# How do I to create a <div> fullscreen?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to create a `<div>` to work as ajax loading. When screen `height` is in `100%` does works fine and fit full screen, the problem is when the screen has more than `100%`, it doesn't auto adjust.

How could I do this ?

trying.

**CSS**

```
/** loading */
#div_loading  {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:11;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:auto;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    background-image: url(../Imagens/ajaxloader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 60px;
    display:none;    
}
```

**Edit**

```
/** loading */
#div_loading  {    
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:11;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100vh;
    height:100vh;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    background-image: url(../Imagens/ajaxloader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 60px;
    display:none;    
}
```

[image]

Comment: you can use 100vh. view hight.??

Comment: @Dinesh do you say `height:100%` ???

Comment: vh means view port height. that means you div takes exactly you screen height. try height:100vh;

Comment: @Dinesh I tried your suggestion and has same problem. Look at the picture.

Comment: inorder to do that you need to set html,body height to 100%. try this code in your css .     **html,body{height:100%;margin:0;padding:0}**

Comment: @Dinesh tried `html, body {height:100% !important;margin:0 !important;padding:0 !important;}` and still doesn't works. By the way, I'm using boostrap 3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145165/discussion-between-dinesh-and-fernandopaiva).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to set html,body height 100% then you can set your div height to 100%. below is the example.

```css
#map {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:11;
    background-color:#000;
    width:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%
    height:auto;
    opacity: .50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=65);
    background-image: url(../Imagens/ajaxloader.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: 60px;

}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.fill { 
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css">
<body>
  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
   <!-- Rest of nav bar chopped from here -->
  </div>
  <div class="container fill">
    <div id="map"></div> <!-- This one wants to be 100% height -->
  </div>
</body>
```